# Why JLabels disappeare?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

Task: There are 2 labels which connect with each other by line, user must be able to move each of the labels with mouse and the connection between lables must move accordingly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


class BackgroundJPanel extends JPanel {

    BackgroundJPanel() {        
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200); 
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 198, 198);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 198, 198);
    }
}


class LinkJPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel[] labels = null;

    LinkJPanel(JLabel[] labelsIn) { 
        labels = labelsIn;
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(labels[0].getX(), labels[0].getY(), 
                   labels[1].getX(), labels[1].getY());
    }
}


class LabelJPanel extends JPanel {

    AllPanel allPanel = null;

    LabelJPanel(AllPanel allPanelIn) {
        allPanel = allPanelIn;
        this.setOpaque(false);

        JLabel[] labels = allPanel.labels;
        labels[0] = new JLabel("11");              
        this.add(labels[0]);                 
        labels[1] = new JLabel("22");            
        this.add(labels[1]);

        MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        this.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
        this.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
    }

    class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        JLabel labelToMove = null;
        int startDeltaX = -1;
        int startDeltaY = -1;

        JLabel whichLabel(MouseEvent e) {            
            for (JLabel label : allPanel.labels) {                
                int deltaX = e.getX() - label.getX();
                int deltaY = e.getY() - label.getY();                
                if ((deltaX >= 0) 
                        && (deltaX < label.getPreferredSize().width) 
                        && (deltaY >= 0) 
                        && (deltaY < label.getPreferredSize().height)) {
                    return label;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {            
            labelToMove = whichLabel(e);              
            if (labelToMove != null) {                
                startDeltaX = labelToMove.getX() - e.getX();
                startDeltaY = labelToMove.getY() - e.getY();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (labelToMove != null) {
                updateLocation(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            labelToMove = null;
        }

        public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e) {            
            int newXCoord = e.getX() + startDeltaX;
            int newYCoord = e.getY() + startDeltaY;            
            labelToMove.setBounds(newXCoord, newYCoord, 
                    labelToMove.getPreferredSize().width, 
                    labelToMove.getPreferredSize().height);                

            //allPanel.backgroundJPanel.repaint();
            allPanel.linkJPanel.repaint();  
        }
    }
}


class AllPanel extends JPanel {  
    BackgroundJPanel backgroundJPanel = null;
    LinkJPanel linkJPanel = null;
    LabelJPanel labelJPanel = null;
    JLabel[] labels = null;

    AllPanel() {        
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        labels = new JLabel[2];  

        backgroundJPanel = new BackgroundJPanel();
        this.add(backgroundJPanel);

        linkJPanel = new LinkJPanel(labels);
        this.add(linkJPanel);  

        labelJPanel = new LabelJPanel(this);
        this.add(labelJPanel); 

        this.setComponentZOrder(backgroundJPanel, 2);
        this.setComponentZOrder(linkJPanel, 1);
        this.setComponentZOrder(labelJPanel, 0);
    }
}


class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyFrame() {

        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.add(new AllPanel());        

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);        
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                new MyFrame();                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use 3 JPanel - one for background, one for draw connection line, one for drawing 2 labels. JPanel for drawing labels has MouseMotion and Mouse listeners. When some mouse action appears code check which one of the label must be move and then change that label coordinates and repaint JPanel with connection line.

All work fine until I try also repaint JPanel with background. If I uncomment the line

```
//allPanel.backgroundJPanel.repaint();
```

after action JLabels and line start disappeare.
Can someone explane why this happen?

Comment: You're breaking the paint chain and null layouts will always give you loads of headaches

Comment: Thanks! It's help - I get what I want. Still I have some questions..